# Emails not showing up in Microsoft Teams

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to send emails to a Microsoft Teams channel using Microsoft Graph Client to the channel's email address, but the messages aren't showing up in the channel. I've verified that the email address is correct and that the email message was sent successfully - the message is in the sent folder of my email client.

I've sent an email to the same address using my Windows Mail client and it worked fine. I've also tried using a webhook to send messages to the channel, which also worked. It seems that the issue is specific to this email method.

In addition, I tried sending a different message text, different subject, and different body types (HTML and Text). All of them are in my sent folder but none showed up on the Teams channel.

Are there any common issues that can prevent emails from showing up in Microsoft Teams? Is there a way to troubleshoot the problem and determine what's causing it?

Here's the code that I'm using to send the email:

```
var client = await AuthService.GetGraphClientAsync();
var email = "someaddress.com@amer.teams.ms";
var msg = new Message()
{
    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
    {
        new() { EmailAddress = new () { Address = email, Name = email } }
    },
    CcRecipients = new List<Recipient>(),
    BccRecipients = new List<Recipient>(),
    Subject = "Test Subject",
    Body = new ItemBody()
    {
        Content = "Test",
        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
    }
};

await client.Me.SendMail(msg, true).Request().PostAsync();
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please raise a support ticket here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-and-service-issues, as this would need debugging and access to logs.